# Overloading of public functions in Controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am new to MVC. I was going through the asp.net site and found this [link](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/asp-net-mvc-controller-overview-cs) where it stated that public methods (actions) cannot be overloaded in controller classes. However in the [site](http://forums.asp.net/t/1502322.aspx/1?Overloading+methods+in+controller) it stated that it can be only be possible if i use `[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]` with one function.

Can you please explain how does AcceptVerbs helps in overloading the function.What it actually does behind the scene?

And in one of my sample application i am able to overload the function by using `[HttpPost]` in one function.What else can be used for overloading?

Answer (score 0):

Basically the rule is that you can handle this when it is responding to different types of requests, so Post/Get/Delete.  (Any of the items in the `HttpVerbs` enumeration)

It is due to the way that it does resolution of the method to call in the controller, and specifying the method allows it to handle resolution.

Answer (score 0):

In ASP.NET MVC, incoming request url should match action of controller. In MVC request processing pipeline, first the controller action is selected, and then the parameters for it are inspected and populated. Imagine what happened if controller had two methods with same name but different signature (overloaded).The c# compiler does not complain, as it understands the code, because it can distinguish between methods based on its parameter signature. But ASP.NET MVC request matching mechanism, as mentioned above, cannot - it first does search for action and only after action is selected, it takes look at its parameters. Because of this, "Public actions in controllers cannot be overloaded" - if there're no difference between methods(actions) other than parameters, action selection in MVC will fail to unambiguously select one. This's where [ActionMethodSelectorAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.actionmethodselectorattribute.aspx) comes into play. This is the base mechanism for developers to affect the way MVC searches for valid action in specified controller. It has the method [`IsValidForRequest()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.actionmethodselectorattribute.isvalidforrequest.aspx) that tells MVC wether action can be selected for usage or not. All of `[AcceptVerbs]`, `[HttpGet]`, `[HttpPost]`, `[HttpPut]`, `[HttpDelete]` and `[HttpNonAction]` derive from this attribute. And bingo - now the method overloading is possible - although actions have got the same name, one of the attributes above (or your custom attribute derived from `ActionMethodSelectorAttribute`) can tell MVC wchich action to select and which one to not. And MVC now unambigously knows wchich action is valid for request. Consider example

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
    // The above HttpGet.IsValidForRequest() called internally 
by mvc will return true only if request is made via HTTP GET
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(MyModel model)
    {
    // The above HttpPost.IsValidForRequest() called internally 
by mvc will return true only if request is made via HTTP POST
    }
    // And so forth with other ActionMethodSelectorAttibute s. As you see, only one action from same named ones is valid for single request when decorated with any of builtin ActionMethodSelectorAttibute
```